# DeclarationError: Undeclared Identifier (Don't know what to declare)

Tags: solidity, remix

I met some issue when editing a template code.
I have a function `payForCommission` and I hope it will auto execute when another function `invest` been called.

Here is the following `invest` function:

```
function invest(address referer, uint units) external {
         require(enabled, "Pool Not Enabled");
         require(units >= minUnits, "Less than Min Units");
         require(units <= maxUnits, "Over than Max Units");

        uint userid = userids[msg.sender];
        if (userid == 0) {
            totalUsers += 1;
            userid = totalUsers;
            userids[msg.sender] = userid;
            emit UserMsg(userid, "Joined", 0);
        }

        User storage user = users[userid];
        if (user.account == address(0)) {
            user.account = msg.sender;
            user.checkpoint = block.timestamp;
        }

        if (user.referer == address(0) && referer != address(0)) {
            if (users[userids[referer]].totalDeposit > 0 && referer != msg.sender && user.totalDeposit == 0) {
                user.referer = referer;
                users[userids[referer]].partners.push(userid);
                processLevelUpdate(referer, msg.sender);

                address parent = referer;
                for (uint i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    if (parent == address(0)) break;
                    levels[userids[parent]].team += 1;
                    parent = users[userids[parent]].referer;
                }
            }
        }

        payForCommission(referer, value); //THE DECLARATION ERROR IS HERE
        processDeposit(units);
        payReferral(referer, units);
    }
```

So here is the following `payForCommission` function:

```
function payForCommission(address referer, uint value) private returns (uint){
            address upline = referer;
    
            uint totalRefOut;
            for (uint i = 0; i < referRate.length; i++) {
                uint uplineId = userids[upline];
                if (uplineId == 0) break;
                if (upline != address(0) && levels[uplineId].level > i) {
                        uint bonus = value * referRate[i] / 1000;
                        totalRefOut = totalRefOut + bonus;
                        token.safeTransfer(upline, bonus);
                        //                    emit PayBonus(upline, bonus);
                        emit UserMsg(uplineId, "RefBonus", bonus);
                        users[uplineId].totalBonus += bonus;
                        if (i == 0) {
                            users[uplineId].directBonus += bonus;
                        }
                    
                    upline = users[uplineId].referer;
                } else break;
            }
    
            for (uint i = 0; i < team.length; i++) {
                uint bonus = value * teamRate / 1000 / team.length;
                totalRefOut += bonus;
                token.safeTransfer(team[i], bonus / team.length);
                //            emit PayBonus(team[i], bonus);
                emit UserMsg(userids[team[i]], "TeamBonus", bonus);
                users[userids[team[i]]].totalBonus += bonus;
                users[userids[team[i]]].teamBonus += bonus;
            }
            
            totalBonus += totalRefOut;
            uint marketingOut = value * marketingFee / 1000;
            token.safeTransfer(marketingWallet, marketingOut);
    
            uint commi = totalRefOut + marketingOut;
            emit Commission(commi);
            return commi;
        }
```

The error show like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't declare `value` variable and consequently you cannot pass it to `payForCommission()` function. You must to declare a value variable like this:

```
uint value = [VALUE_VARIABLE];
```

And then you can pass it into `payForCommission()` function